# Mostrar resultados de una búsqueda en base de datos, sin refrescar la página completa?

Tags: asp.net

Utilizo Asp.net para Web con el framework 3.5

Estoy usando una ventana modal, el cual contiene varios controles de lo cuales hay uno en especifico que me sirve para hacer una búsqueda en mi base de datos.

Este control es un imagebutton el cual realiza correctamente la búsqueda pero el problema es que se refresca la página por completo y tengo que volver abrir el modal para ver el resultado de la búsqueda.

Ya intente con un updatepanel pero al estar mis controles dentro de un panel no me lo permite.

```
<asp:Panel ID="vtModal" runat="server" CssClass="ContenedorModal">
                    <div class="titulo_modal">
                        <p class="fw-bold text-primary text-uppercase" align="center">Agregar cliente</p>
                        <br />
                    </div>
                    <div class="Contvcc">
                        
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtCpostal" runat="server" placeholder="Código postal" CssClass="field_auto" OnTextChanged="txtCpostal_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>&nbsp
                            <asp:ImageButton ID="imgbtnBuscascp" runat="server" Height="35px" ImageUrl="~/clientes/img/btn-busca-cliente.png" OnClick="imgbtnBuscascp_Click" Width="37px" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtDel" runat="server" placeholder="Delegación o Municipio" CssClass="field_auto"></asp:TextBox>&nbsp;
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtLocal" runat="server" placeholder="Localidad" CssClass="field_auto"></asp:TextBox>&nbsp;
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtEst" runat="server" placeholder="Estado" CssClass="field_auto"></asp:TextBox>&nbsp;
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlColonias" runat="server" CssClass="field_auto"></asp:DropDownList>

                            
                        </div>
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <asp:Button ID="btnGuardaCliente" runat="server" Text="Agregar" CssClass=" btn btn-primary py-2 px-4 ms-3" OnClick="btnGuardaCliente_Click" Style="border-radius: 5px;" />
                            <asp:Button ID="btnModalCerrar" runat="server" Text="Cerrar" CssClass=" btn btn-primary py-2 px-4 ms-3" Style="border-radius: 5px;" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </asp:Panel>
```

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow, te invito a hacer el [tour]. Edité tu pregunta y, entre otras cosas, agregué la etiqueta [tag:asp.net], que creo que es lo que usas y tu pregunta tiene mucho más que ver con asp.net (o asp clásico si es lo que usas) que con SQL, que diría que no tiene nada que ver. El uso de etiquetas es importante porque muchos usuarios monitorean etiquetas específicas según su área de conocimiento y esos son principalmente quienes pueden responder a tu pregunta.

Comment: Buenas, cuando trabajas con ASP.Net, al ejecutar la acción de submit o generar peticiones la página se va a recargar automáticamente, para evitar esto necesitas verificar el uso de AJAX para envío de datos al servidor. te dejo un link donde puedes revisar más documentación del tema.  [enlace](https://www.rafaelacosta.net/Blog/2020/1/4/formularios-web-ajax-en-aspnet-web-forms-updatepanel?AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1#:~:text=Formularios%20web%20AJAX%20en%20ASP.NET%20Web%20Forms%20-,...%203%20Aplicando%20la%20asincron%C3%ADa%20-%20AJAX%20)